# Cannot initialize const int from unpacked tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, stdtuple

Question is really simple, why is this code not working:

```
#include <tuple>

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int a,b = std::tie(std::make_pair(1,2));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

g++ gives me this error:

> ./test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: ./test.cpp:4:13:
>   error: uninitialized const ‘a’ [-fpermissive]    const int a,b =
>   std::tie(std::make_pair(1,2));
>                ^ ./test.cpp:4:42:
>
> ***error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::pair&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::pair’
>
>   const int a,b = std::tie(std::make_pair(1,2));***

I cannot get any tuple-like return by value, using this kind of pattern (either const or non const). Is it a better way to do what I am trying to achieve here ?

Comment: `std::tie` does not "unpack" tuples and C++ is not Python. This looks like you are writing C++ based on guessing, which does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
const int a,b = std::tie(...)
```

This isn't doing what you think it is. It's creating two `const int` variables:

- `a`, uninitialized
- `b`, initialized to `std::tie(...)`

---

The proper way of using `std::tie` is as follows:

```
int a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

Note that you need `a` and `b` to be already declared and non-`const`.

---

In C++17, you can use *structured bindings* instead:

```
const auto [a, b] = std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

Comment: Yes, I am really dumb, I just realized that 1 minute ago. Cannot delete question now.

Comment: @Tobbey - Good. Vittorio doesn't deserve to have his effort go down the drain because you had an "oops" moment. That's why SO prohibits you from deleting.

Comment: You are right, anyway despite my comment Vittorio Romeo answer is interesting because I discovered that c++17 allows to do exactly what I want.